# How to increase WASAPI audio buffer in windows 10?

Tags: windows, audio

We use a widespread softphone solution. When CPU usage rise slightly (40%) the sound start having crackles and glitches.

After investigation I found on [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/low-latency-audio) that :

> In Windows 10, the latency has been reduced to 1.3ms for all
>   applications
>
> Before Windows 10, this buffer was always set to ~10ms.

1.3ms looks crazy low for me, is there a way to increase it ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not found out how to increase the audio buffer. But turning on Windows 8 or 7 compatibility mode for the program solved the issue.